# How to eliminate an "[" from a column?

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains a column called calories but all the values start with a "[". We want to do numerical analysis, but the [ is impeding that. We've tried with both gsub and regex.

Currently, our data looks like this:

Calories

[235

[456

[876

And we would like to make it look like this:

Calories

235

456

876

Many thanks!

Comment: Not quite! We want to keep other special characters in other columns, but the only one that must go is that [.

Answer (score 2):

Try `substr` or `gsub`:

```
df$Calories <- substr(df$Calories,2,nchar(df$Calories))
```

or

```
df$Calories <- gsub("^\\[(.*)","\\1",df$Calories)
```

such that

```
> df
  Calories
1      235
2      456
3      876
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Calories = c("[235", "[456", "[876")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```